# WHM - Apache Configuration Include Editor - Syntax Error

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

My server is running Cloudlinux 5 + EasyApache 3. PHP Handler = fcgi.

I'm trying to set "FcgidOutputBufferSize" per request_uri. Here is what I put into WHM->Apache Configuration->Include Editor->Post Virtual Host Include:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidBusyTimeout 18000
FcgidIOTimeout 18000
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/path/to/script.php'">
FcgidOutputBufferSize 0
</If>
</IfModule>
```

This is the error I got after saving:

```
Configuration problem detected on line 5 of file /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf: Invalid command ' 2FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824 3FcgidBusyTimeout 18000 4FcgidIOTimeout 18000 5 ===> <=== 6 FcgidOutputBufferSize 0 7 8 --- /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf ---
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.